# JS or jquery to auto style/highlight matched words as typed

Tags: jquery, coding-style, textarea, highlight

I need to be able to style/format text when specific words are typed into a content-editable iframe on the fly. For instance say the word "danger" was one of the key words, when the user types the word danger into  the content-editable it wraps that word in a div that makes the word bold and red. JS Bin type functionality for their syntax highlighting as you type is what I'm trying to achieve, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely check out [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/)... it is used by jsFiddle actually. Once you've installed it, I'm pretty sure you could create your own stylesheets and your own syntax highlighting. It might involve some extra coding but it will be totally worth it!

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks I will check it out, one thing I forgot to mention is that the words that need to be parsed/formated on the fly will be dynamic, an array of words to match would be generated dynamically each page load, not pre-defined words since the words are based on user specific settings

Comment: hmm... that makes it more difficult. I'm sure you could still do it though, but it will take some reading through the code to understand how it works. You could also probably just email the dude that wrote CodeMirror and ask him if what you are trying to do can be done with CodeMirror... his email is on the site.